# Is there any way to make a small dynamic site using cloud services with a cost cap?

Tags: database, cloud-service

By cloud services I mean something that provides or makes it possible to set up:

- A "database": almost anything that provides centralised persistent state, see below.  By centralised, I mean I'm not talking about per-client state like cookies or IndexedDB: the purpose of this site involves some information moving between users of the site, which is why I want to use a server-side database of some kind.
- Some means of serving a public HTTP API ("serverless" would do, as probably would some other solution)
- Plus serving some static files: a few HTML / JS / CSS files that will interact with the public HTTP endpoints

Shared hosting would meet all those criteria of course, but I'm explicitly excluding that from this question because the existence of that type of service is well known, and I'm looking for alternatives to that.  So more concretely, by cloud service, I mean... whatever people mean by that, really: no hard definitions here, I'm just trying to keep this question focused on solutions away from the shared hosting market.  Use your skill and judgement ;-)

By cost cap I mean: if you go over a certain amount of money per day, it's possible, without doing a lot of work, to arrange that service reliably ceases and your liability is thereby reliably limited if you make some silly mistake and a billion people start using your site in some unanticipated way.  I don't count "AWS are nice sometimes" as a suitable form of cost cap.  I don't count either "some aspects of our cloud service have cost limits" -- rather I want a hard cost cap on all spending with all cloud services I could possibly end up getting billed for.

By "database", I'm defining that very broadly -- I don't have many requirements I'm aware of:

- Not Google (that means not Firebase, for example)
- Simple key/value store would be fine, as would SQL, or in a pinch even the ability to write and read a JSON file to/from disk (but see above re the focus of this question being away from the "cheap shared hosting" market)
- Write throughput will be perhaps 10 writes per day at peak, more likely 0 or 1 in any given day
- Read throughput is harder to predict but I'd be very surprised if more than 10000 / day.  More likely less than 10 / day ;-)
- Reads, at minimum, will involve simply fetching the last value written

Public HTTP API:

- Language could be anything, but I know Python and JavaScript so they would be convenient
- See under database above re throughput

The cost limits requirement means, for example the following are unsuitable, to my knowledge:

- AWS
- Azure

In fact I have never seen any cloud service provider that offers cost limits (except by means of a free tier, but I have not seen a free tier that provides a means of serving an HTTP API and maintaining some persistent state).

Fake internet bonus points will be awarded for something that would work with netlify, because I'm already using that for a static site.  Not essential!

This is for a personal project, not a business.

Comment: Are you looking for software – or for a hosting provider?

Comment: I'm looking for cloud services -- that's to say: kind of both, kind of neither. But as I emphasize in the question, "cloud services" in general certainly are not the same market as "hosting", conventionally understood

Comment: Yeah, those are kind of a "grey area" and, in dubio pro reo, could be counted as "web apps". Your question is just a bit difficult as it seems to ask for multiple "web apps" ;)

Comment: I'm looking for one solution that lets me *write* web apps, and I don't care that much in principle how many cloud services that solution is made up of.  Is that what you were getting at with 'multiple "web apps"'?  Not sure I understood...

Comment: Yepp, that's where I got lost a bit (looking for a database … and API … then some hosting criteria (which brought up my original question)… Never mind me then. Those who are working in the field will understand; I just wanted to make sure it's on-topic (which a pure hosting question would not have been). I'm no fan of cloud services, my stuff runs on-premise and is basically LAMP, my APIs/CMS are self-written with "local resources". So all I can do now is wishing you best luck for good and fitting recommendations!